# Proper way to program in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to Common Lisp, and found myself taking advantage of way functions returns values. The following are to two trivial examples:

```
(defun safe-avg (a b)
    (and (numberp a) (numberp b) (/ (+ a b) 2)))

(defun safe-div (a b)
    (and (numberp a) (numberp b) (> b 0) (/ a b)))
```

But I could've written it like this (arguably clearer):

```
(defun safe-avg (a b)
    (if (and (numberp a) (numberp b))
        (/ (+ a b) 2)))

(defun safe-div (a b)
    (if (and (numberp a) (numberp b) (> b 0))
        (/ a b)))
```

I wanted to know what is the preferred method of doing something like this and the reasoning behind it, before I start abusing this habit.

Comment: I would use the 2nd form. Why? Because it's "less tricky" and shows the intent better. I value code readability -- both now and in 6 months from now.

Comment: I was used to scheme, are you sure the function are equivalent? To me not, as the first couple of function return false if the constraint are not meet the second one seems not specify a return value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you do not use the "else" branch, you could use `when`:

```
(defun safe-div (a b)
  (when (and (numberp a) (numberp b) (> b 0))
    (/ a b)))
```

which is the same as:

```
(defun safe-div (a b)
  (if (and (numberp a) (numberp b) (> b 0))
      (/ a b)
      nil))
```

which is the same as your version, but more explicit.

Anyway, these are all functionally equivalent.  I would rather think about how these functions are to be used.  If you do it like this, you will have to do null checks each time you call these functions, which is tedious.

It would be better to use conditions, either through type declarations, through asserts, or through explicit `when` … `signal` forms.  You can then define handlers and restarts for these conditions for entire parts of your program.  Further reading: [Practical Common Lisp, ch. 19](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html).

In this case, I would not handle this here at all:

```
(defun safe-div (a b)
  (/ a b))
```

(or rather, just use `/`).

If `/` gets the wrong arguments, it will signal an error which you can then handle outside, where you know what that could mean.

Answer (score 3):

The first form is idiomatically acceptable.  It isn't the best example of using `AND`'s return value effectively, since the second form is a little clearer without being any lengthier.  But you shouldn't be afraid to use LISP as intended!

For instance, going in an (inadvisable) direction...someone might argue that the implicit "nil return" of `if` statements could be confusing and try and parallel `if/else` structure to be more clear:

```
(defun safe-avg (a b)
  (cond ((and (numberp a) (numberp b))
         (/ (+ a b) 2))
        (t
         nil)))
```

*That's bad.*  And you don't want to go down that road.  So go ahead and use the expressions and trim the amount of code with nice evaluations, and use comments to pick up the slack to remind others (and yourself) of how it works if there's anything non-obvious about it.

Comment: Someone downvoted this, and gave no reason (always an annoyance).  So I edited to be clearER that I'm not suggesting the code sample is a good idea.  It's a purposefully bad example so you realize embracing the "LISP way" of programming is a good direction.  But whatever.

Comment: Actually, I really like the COND approach.  IF and WHEN are just syntactic sugar for COND anyway. :-)  COND is generally clearer when there are one or more than two test conditions.  I should admit that I still use CAR and CDR instead of the current politically correct versions.

Comment: @ArtTaylor I actually wrote it this way because I looked up `if` and didn't see the else handling in the documentation on the site I found.  (I don't know common lisp in particular, just languages like it, and I plugged this into an interpreter I installed and it worked.)  Point remains, I still think that throwing in the "nil" clause instead of letting the if return nil implicitly is too much the C-style language mindset...

Comment: Ah, that's funny.  I was coming from the functional programming mindset, where undefined results are bad. :-)

Comment: Due to your confusing whitespace splattering, you have garbled up the first cond clause.

Comment: @Svante - Garbled how?  It copies and pastes into the interpreter I got with `sudo apt-get install clisp` and seems to work as expected.  What doesn't work?  Also, due to you picking on a body of code trying to demonstrate "don't do this" you are missing the point.

Comment: @HostileFork: Typically, you wrap the tests inside the and and put the return value outside the condition. However, if COND is not given a return value, it'll return the value of the test, so this (maybe accidentally) works.

Comment: @ArtTaylor: These days, COND is usually a macro on top of IF.

Comment: @Vatine Well again I've used LISP-like langauges but not Common Lisp.  Just felt like tinkering with it since someone asked a question which arises in the whole family of languages (such as in Rebol).  I was following along with a tutorial, where they use `t` for something that always evaluates to truth, so the last clause always matches and returns nil.  See: http://www.n-a-n-o.com/lisp/cmucl-tutorials/LISP-tutorial-17.html

Comment: @HostileFork You put the `(/ (+ a b) 2)` inside the `and` clause.  That's what Svante was talking about.  I've fixed it.

Comment: @Vatine True, I think CLISP does that. SBCL still just uses COND macros. Many of the others cheat and use C or asm for "performance".

Comment: @MatthiasBenkard I see.  Thanks for fixing--a far friendlier gesture than downvoting and being pretentious like... *some people*.  :P